# Logo image not being displayed Except on the default page

Tags: html, webmatrix-2

I'm working on a website. I have linked the logo image file. The logo is displayed only once when the site runs on the default page i.e. the home page. As I switch on to the other page the logo is not displayed on any page. I have given the correct source path, can anyone help me out on this?

```
<div id="header">
    <a href="Default.cshtml"><img src="Images/logo2.jpg" alt="Twenty47"   
       style="width:285px; height:250px; margin-top:5px; margin-left:5px;margin-bottom: 0px" /></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you give us a link to your site? Or some code?

Comment: <div id="header">
            <a href="Default.cshtml"><img src="Images/logo2.jpg" alt="Twenty47" style="width:285px; height:250px; margin-top:5px; margin-left:5px;margin-bottom: 0px " /></a>
        </div>

Comment: Have you tried setting the path relatively to the root? `src="/Images/logo2.jpg"`

Comment: Please add code to the question (use the 'edit' link below the tags), code in the comments is near-useless because of the lack of formatting.

Comment: Thank u @Oriol i was missing / in the path.

Comment: @kid If that solved your problem, I have added an answer with the solution, please mark it as accepted answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted a comment: *Have you tried setting the path relatively to the root? `src="/Images/logo2.jpg"`*. And it seems it was that.

So if somebody has the same problem and comes here, the solution is:

**Add `/` at the beginning of the path in order to make it relative to site's root.**

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget the file extensions .jpg and .jpeg are not the same. Webmatrix requires that you use the correct one.